# I checked out one file, then I don't want to modify it, how to put it back?

Tags: git

On git, 
I checked out one file, then I didn't want to modify it, how to put it back?

Or I can just do nothing?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are thinking about checkout in git sense, or is that a notion made by you. Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't work with a "checkout/checkin" system. `git checkout` is actually just a way of setting your working directory to a particular branch/commit for examination; it doesn't actually "lock" or otherwise indicate an intent to make modifications.

Basically, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to revert the changes use

```
git checkout file_name
```

If you need to commit your changes use

```
git add file_name
git commit -m 'Comment here'
```